# Order decimals in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using entity framework to get data from a table and sort that data by a decimal column
How do i order that data in the correct way in linq?
i allready tried

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)
```

but this gives a wrong result

```
12.0
1.0
2.0
2.5
3.0
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: That's probably because you're storing the numbers in strings.

Comment: they are decimals in the table

Comment: I would agree with @Rob, if they are strings you'll need to apply a natural sort provider to them.

Comment: `list.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.DisplayOrder))`

Comment: @LuísTiago In that case.. are you assigning the result of `OrderBy` to anything? It's not an in-place sort

Comment: try this: list.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.DisplayOrder))

Comment: @LuísTiago - are you sure they are `decimals`? can you show the mapping? the declaration of the type of `x`?

Comment: Downvoted for not telling us what `list` and `DisplayOrder` are (how they are defined, how they are filled).

Comment: question updated sorry for the bad explanation

Comment: @LuísTiago - is still doesn't show the definition of the table and classes...

Comment: @Gilad Green - sry for the confusion, your awnser works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your `DisplayOrder` a string? If so it is ordering it by the alphabetic order instead if the numeric. Parse to `decimal`:

```
list.OrderBy(x => decimal.Parse(x.DisplayOrder))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<decimal> list= new List<decimal>() {12.123m,14m,10.85m,124.0003m};

foreach (var  item  in list.OrderBy(c=>c))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```